# How to attach and detach Portable storage disk in virtual server?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-storage

I want to attach and detach portable storage from Virtual server using Rest API. I didn't find any API references related to attach and detach from portable storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following examples:

Attach Portable storage

Method POST

```
https://username:apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[#Virtual_GuestID]/attachDiskImage
```

Body

```
 {
"parameters":[ 
         [#Image_Id]
]}
```

Detach Portable storage

Method POST

```
https://username:apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[#Virtual_GuestID]/detachDiskImage
```

Body

```
 {
"parameters":[ 
         [#Image_Id]
]}
```

Note: Keep in mind that you have to change the [#Virtual_GuestId] and [#Image_Id] according to the selected datacenter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the API reference provided by you. The API provided is related to Block volumes, but I require the API related to portable storage attach and detach.

Please provide the same.

I even tried editing the API provided by you and used it for Portable storage ID. I am getting the below-mentioned error.

{"error":"Please provide a valid SoftLayer_Network_Storage object to allow access.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_MissingParameter"}" Body : { "parameters":[{ "id": 99584837 }]}

Comment: right, these examples are to attach and dettach block storage, I need to upgrade my response